# Password protect admin panel using htpassword not working

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have created a simple CSM website using core PHP. I have placed my fronted code in root directory i.e. `public_html` and admin code inside admin directory i.e. `public_html/admin.`

I want to password protect my admin part with htpassword. Below is my code for `admin/.htaccess` file.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/public_html/admin/.htpasswd
ErrorDocument 401 /admin
Require valid-user
```

I have also added redirect from http to https in root `.htaccess` file as below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

htpassword for admin only working if I will remove above code from root .htaccess file.

Anything wrong is there?

Answer (score 0):

Create `.htpasswd` file in your **admin** folder.

And then create username and password by using this link : [Click Here](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/)

Paste the below code in your `.htaccess` file.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile COMPLETE_PATH_TO_ADMIN_FOLDER/.htpasswd #complete path to .htpasswd file.
require valid-user
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that both of your file should be readable to the Web Server i.e **.htpasswd and .htaccess** use **chmod 644** for the trick to work.

Try using my code in your **.htaccess** file

```
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Secret Folder"
Require valid-user
```

I hope it works :D